# Is there a way to make it faster and more generic to do this question?

Tags: java

I am trying solve this question

> You are given an input file which will start with a single integer N (1≤N≤10000) denoting the number of test cases. The following N lines will contain sets of 3 numbers a,b,c (1≤a,b,c≤10000). For each test case, determine whether or not it is possible to produce the third number, using any* two numbers, using addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division.

For Instance

```
Input(1)             Output(1)
6                    Possible
1 2 3                Possible
2 24 12              Impossible
5 3 1                Possible
9 16 7               Possible
7 2 14               Impossible
12 4 2
```

I have solved this question by using this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int noOfInput = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        String[] output = new String[noOfInput];
        for (int i = 0; i< noOfInput;i++){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            int c = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
            output[i] = isPossible(a,b,c);
        }
        for (int j =0;j<noOfInput; j++)
            System.out.println(output[j]);
    }
    public static String isPossible(int a, int b, int c){
        String output = "";
        if (a+b == c|| a-b ==c||a*b ==c) // Do not need divide because a/b == c is just c*b == a
            output = "Possible";
        else if (a+c == b|| a-c ==b||a*c ==b)
            output = "Possible";
        else if (b+c == a||b-c == a||b*c == a)
            output = "Possible";
        else
            output = "Impossible";
        return output;
    }
}
```

I understand that it will work for this question however, if the question becomes ""The following N lines will contain sets of X numbers"" then my code will become invalid. Hence, is there any way to make this more generic.

Comment: The general solution is much more complicated than that for the stated problem because the combination of operations increases geometrically with the number of operands.

Comment: In general solution you should be picking each element and then for the rest N - 1 numbers build permutations, and then try to apply N - 2 operations to each permutation.